# Display data from mysql row separated with comma as a link to an image

Tags: php

I have a `row['cities']` in my table. There are different city's name in that `row` separated with comma and spaces (London, New York,   Tokyo,    Miami, ...). The goal is to create a link for each city name like `img/london.png`
I need to get the names from `row['cities']`, remove comma and whatever space is after comma and before the city's name, and then add `img/` before that city's name and add `.png` after the city's name.

I did the following but because the empty space after comma is not one space for all cities and sometimes is more than one empty space, then the code didn't work for all city's name and it just works for those city's name that has one empty space after comma!

```
    $data = array($row['cities']);
    $city = explode(', ', $data[0]);
    $cities = $city[ rand(0, count($city)-1) ];
    $citylink = "img/".$cities.".png";
```

What is the best way to do this and be able to remove all empty space between comma and city's name or perhaps there is a better way to solve this problem?
Thanks,

Comment: What exactly is random about this data? It seems your post title is not in-line with the body...

Comment: use trim function to remove spaces.http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a link for each city, explode the string with comma as delimiter and loop it to generate image src.

```
$data = array('London, New York,   Tokyo, Miami  ');
$cities = explode(', ', $data[0]);
// loop the cities
foreach($cities as $city){
    $trimmed_city = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $city); //trim city for white spaces
    echo "img/".$trimmed_city.".png"; // create image src
    echo "\n";  // new line
}
```

Out put:

```
img/London.png
img/NewYork.png
img/Tokyo.png
img/Miami.png
```

Comment: That is great but how to fix New York.png?  because right now there is an empty space inside `img/New York.png`

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = array($row['cities']);
$city = explode(', ', $data[0]);
$cities = $city[ rand(0, count($city)-1) ];

$citylink = "img/".trim($cities).".png";
```